# Authenticate domain user after connection to domain is inaccessible C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, windows-authentication

We have an MVC application that validates windows users by instantiating a principalcontext, locally and for domain users. However, this immediately fails when a connection to the domain cannot be made. Is there a way to leverage the capability of windows to still validate domain credentials when disconnected from the domain?

We see that in SSMS you can also use windows authentication after the server has lost access to the domain.

To be clear, the machine is joined to the domain but does not have access to the domain controller, i.e. a corporate laptop that is taken home.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I understand your problem, but I don't understand what you mean about SSMS. Are you talking about the SQL server losing access to the domain and you can still authenticate to it with a domain account?

Comment: I'm talking about Sql Server Management Studio, you can still basically login and access the database even after you're disconnected to the domain

Comment: Right, but in that case the *server* still has access to the domain. Why would your website be losing access to the domain?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, the application has a mobile vs central instances. The mobile instances are installed while connected to the domain but can be used while disconnected to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in how Kerberos (and I believe NTLM is similar) works in that they use [session tickets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/session-tickets). So once authentication is successful against a domain controller, you have a "ticket" that proves you authenticated. When you authenticate to anything else that requires Windows authentication, the ticket is sent.

To take advantage of this, you must use the built-in Windows authentication. You cannot take a username and password and try to authenticate them that way.

If everyone who uses your website can use Windows authentication - then you can enable it for your whole site.

If you have a mixed audience - some who have a domain account and some that don't - it's a little trickier, but still doable. I've done it. You can look at the [OWIN-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/Owin-MixedAuth) project. I haven't used that specifically.

That project seems to use a separate button for the Windows authentication. When I did it, I made it seamless (it tries Windows auth and fails back to a login page). I did that by doing an AJAX request in the background to a page that requires Windows authentication, and if it succeeds, just forward on. If it fails, show the login fields.

All that said, I don't know it will work if the server cannot reach the domain. It will probably work for users who have already authenticated to the site before it lost connection to the domain, or if the site is hosted on the same computer that it is being accessed from. But it might not work if a user it has never seen before tries to login while there is no access to the domain. You will have to test.

But the benefit of using Windows authentication anyway is that you can make the login seamless. As long as the site is in your Trusted Sites (in the Windows Internet Options) then IE and Chrome will automatically send the user's credentials.

Comment: Hi Gabriel! Although this is a very good and detailed answer, we require that both domain and local user be able to login to the web app. Also, we require the user to supply the credentials since it's not always the user who logged in to windows will be logging in to the app. 

We found a possible solution that's quite simple but we're still validating it.

Comment: Allowing both domain and local users is not a problem with the solution I proposed. If you want it to always prompt for credentials, then just don't add it to the Trusted Sites and the browser will ask for credentials.

Comment: If you do find another solution, let me know what it is. I'm curious.